# Gaussian stochastic integral

Tags: probability, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

first question here :)

I am reading an article about the Heston model and stochastic volatility, in which they state the following: "because the process for $V_t$ is independent of the brownian motion $W_t$, the distribution of $\int_u^t \sqrt{V_s} \, dW_s$ is normal with mean $0$ and variance $\int_u^t V_s \, ds$". This statement is very similar to the one I know, which is the case of a deterministic function $f(t)$ instead of the variance process $V_t$. However I have never heard before a version of this where we consider a stochastic process independent of a brownian motion, hence I don't quite understand why this is true.

Does anyone have a (sketch of) proof of the first statement ? Or any reference where I could find it ? Thanks !

Comment: This is nonsense. I don't even want to know where you read this. When $V_t$ is random (may it be independent of $W_t$ or not) then $\int_u^tV_s\,ds$ can ***never ever*** be a variance.

Comment: From the Ito isometry  it follows that the variance of $\int_0^t\sqrt{V_s}\,dW_s$ is $\int_u^t\mathbb E[V_s]\,ds\,.$

Comment: Hum this is interesting, although not quite what I was hoping to read. Now from my understanding the Ito isometry would basically give $E[(\int_u^t \sqrt{V_s} \, dW_s)^2]=E[\int_u^t V_s \, ds]$, which also implies that $Var[\int_u^t \sqrt{V_s} \, dW_s]=E[\int_u^t V_s ds]$. But indeed this does not answer the statement. In case you are wondering, I am reading Broadie&Kaya 2006's article, and I stumbled across it on page 222. Since I assume it somehow has to be correct, I guess I don't understand (or explain) it the right way.

Comment: They write something very important, namely, that the distribution of $\int_u^t\sqrt{V_s}\,dW_s\,,$ ***given the path generated by*** $V_t\,,$  is normal with mean $0$ and variance $\int_u^tV_s\,ds\,.$ Hint from my side: Conditional expectations, tower property and so on.

Comment: Oh sure, I didn't really grasp how the condition on the path generated by $V_t$ was any useful but it makes perfect sense. Moreover I feel like conditionally to the path generated by $V_t$ up to time $t$ the process $V_t$ can be considered as deterministic, since its values arer known, which may be why it seemed so close to the deterministic case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A stochastic integral $\int_0^tU_s\,dW_s$ is in general not Gaussian when the integrand is not deterministic, even if $U$ and the Brownian motion $W$ are independent. Take for example
$$
U_s=1_{\{s\le \tau\}}
$$
where $\tau$ is independent of $W$ and exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda\,.$
Then
$$
\int_0^tU_s\,dW_s=W_{\tau\wedge t}\,.
$$
Conditional on $\tau\,,$  $W_{\tau\wedge t}$ has variance $\tau\wedge t\,.$ Therefore its characteristic function  is
\begin{align}
\mathbb E\left[e^{i\,x\,W_{\tau\wedge t}}\right]&=
\mathbb E\left[e^{-\frac12x^2(\tau\wedge t)}\right]
=\lambda\int_0^te^{-\frac12x^2u}e^{-\lambda u}\,du+\lambda\int_t^\infty e^{-\frac12x^2t}e^{-\lambda u}\,du\\
&=\lambda \frac{1-e^{-(\frac{x^2}2+\lambda) t}}{\frac{x^2}{2}+\lambda}+e^{-(\frac{x^2}2+\lambda) t}\,.
\end{align}
If $W_{\tau\wedge t}$ were Gaussian this should however be of the form
$e^{-\frac12x^2\sigma^2}\,.$

Comment: Nice this is very helpful, thanks a lot !

Comment: @AdenaMk if this contribution answers your question, please do accept it if you want.